# Can I receive Upstream Messages from Devices via Firebase Admin SDK without implementing XMPP on application server

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, xmpp, firebase-admin

I am implementing an application server in java to send Data Messages to android devices via FCM. I need to receive upstream messages from android devices.

Is it possible to receive upstream messages from devices in application server only via use of Firebase Admin SDK and without implementing XMPP protocol on application server?

Comment: @Frank Can you pls help me hereby?

Answer (score 0):

Admin SDK does not provide an API for receiving messages.

Does it have to be FCM though? If all you need is a way to pass some information from devices to the server, that can be easily achieved using Realtime Database or Firestore.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. In fact it has to work with FCM since I need to Push downstream Data from App Server to devices and get upstream messages from devices to server (such as receive confirmation, registration token, device Id registration..etc). So what Admin SDK allows me to do? Can I implement HTTP and XMPP protocol in parallel or only one alternative has to be followed?

Comment: Admin SDK allows you to implement the downstream path. You will have to implement upstream/XMPP path yourself.